# Override css with access only to body

Tags: css, frameworks, load

Hi I have a framework which has its own CSS codes.. I m trying to make some in styles in the body where I have access. But any CSS I write here is overridden by framework's CSS... I need to be able to load my CSS in the end? So that it overrides framework CSS. How could I do this when I only have access to write in the body of the page? Thank for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

you could try a "!important" at the end of your rules;

```
    color: #444 !important;
```

if this doesn't work and you want to style something in your scope (your accessible part of the page) you could use inline-css(yeah, i know):

```
    <div style="color: #444">Lorem</div>
```